# Regex to match two elements or none

Tags: javascript, regex, numbers, match, parentheses

I've been trying to get a regular expression that allows me to match numbers in parentheses, for example:

`^([^02-9])?(\s)?((\(?)[0-9]{3}(\3\)?))(\s|\-)?[0-9]{3}(\s|\-)?[0-9]{4}$`

It is the expression that I have tried to use, but it is also valid when there is only one parenthesis, which does not work for me. Is there any way I could do this?

My expression should work for cases where there is "(123)" and where only "123" exists, but not for "(123" or "123)"

Comment: What is the back-reference `\3` supposed to refer to? You only have 2 capture groups before that.

Comment: I didn't upload the full regexp before, sorry, here it is: `^([^02-9])?(\s)?((\(?)[0-9]{3}(\3\)?))(\s|\-)?[0-9]{3}(\s|\-)?[0-9]{4}$`

Comment: Could you please  clarify what `[^02-9]` is supposed to match?

Answer (score 0):

Just use two different expressions as alternatives. The first uses negative lookarounds to match 3 digits without parentheses around it, the second matches 3 digits surrounded by parentheses.

```
(?<!\()\d{3}(?!\))|\(\d{3}\)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yLzxoG/1)

Comment: In that case, you may choose to mark this solution as *accepted*.